# Unique ergodicity on finite set

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let X be a finite set with a $\sigma$-algebra B = $2^X$ and let T : X → X be uniquely ergodic. The latter means that there exists the only one probabilistic invariant measure. Find all pairs of positive integers p,q such that for any points x, y $\in$ X there exists n = n(p, q, x, y, X)  $\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $T^{pn}x$ = $T^{qn}$y.

I have trouble finding anything I learnt useful to start. I think it maybe related to rotation.

Comment: Hint: If a dynamical system can be split into two parts that are disjoint, topologically closed, and invariant under the dynamics, then it's not uniquely ergodic (can you see why?). So your $(X, T)$ can't have a splitting like this.